# It gives value in textbox but only after finishing it . how to display data while running timer?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

        Me.TextBox1.Text = "hello"

 Dim connectionString As String = "Data Source=192.168.0.199;Initial Catalog=NEWDATABASE;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=admin;Password=123456"
        Dim connection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
        connection.Open()

        Dim sql As String = "SELECT TOP (" & topvalue & ") * FROM [NEWDATABASE].[dbo].[MachineParameter] WHERE status = '0' ORDER BY Id ASC"
        Dim dataadapter As New SqlDataAdapter(sql, connection)
        Dim ds As New DataSet()

        dataadapter.Fill(ds, "table")

        DataGridViewtx.DataSource = ds
        DataGridViewtx.DataMember = "table"
connection.close()
end sub
```

Comment: Hi, can you clarify what you're after please? The timer isn't "running", it's a trigger to retrieve and display the data. thanks

Comment: [`Application.DoEvents`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.applicationservices.windowsformsapplicationbase.doevents?view=netframework-4.7.2)?

Comment: @preciousbetine : You should _**NEVER, EVER**_ use or even suggest `Application.DoEvents()`. It is used by the internal methods of the Framework when showing modal dialogs. It is _**not**_ meant to be used as a workaround to keep the UI responsive instead of using actual multithreading or the Task Parallel Library. -- This may seem harsh, but `DoEvents()` is extremely overused, and when used incorrectly (which it always is) causes more problems than it solves.

Comment: when this timer ticks it runs this code and many more for data fetching and sending etc. so i want to display some text like "data is being transffered" or something like that but it does't show like that..:(

Comment: If the data takes a long time to be fetched then it will block the entire UI and prevent it from redrawing. If that's the case you need to look into multithreading or the Task Parallel Library, since the code would need to be run in the background so that it doesn't freeze your UI.

Comment: thanks i will look into it only doubt is my progressbar is showing increment ..